# create built-in chromium extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm building a web browser on top of chromium source code (actually I just customize things like appearance, webstore url, policy storage).

The question is - is it possible to create extension that is embedded in chromium resource file? I have seen some `manifest.json` files is chromium source tree (for example here `//src/ui/keyboard/resources/manifest.json`). And how can I load such extension?

I know that I can use `ExtensionInstallForcelist` policy, but it is not the case because user can delete an extension  from `User Data` directory, and browser needs an internet connection to install this extention.